# Modelling a positive edge triggered T flip flop with asynchronous clear

Tags: verilog

I am modelling a positive edge triggered T flip flop with asynchronous clear. Here is the code :

```
module t_flip_flop_exam (q,clk,clear,t);
  input t ;
  input clk;
  input clear;
  output reg q ;
  reg internal_t;
  always @ (clear)begin
    if (clear==1)
      q=0;
    else 
      q=q;
  end
  always @ (posedge clk)begin
        if (t==1)
          q=~q;
        else 
          q=q;
     
  end
  
endmodule
```

Is this is an efficient code?  Is it ok to have to separate `always` blocks, or is there is a way to include both the `clear` and the `clk` signals behavioral code in a single `always` block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common way to combine the `always` blocks:

```
module t_flip_flop_exam (q,clk,clear,t);
    input t;
    input clk;
    input clear;
    output reg q;

    always @(posedge clk or posedge clear) begin
        if (clear)
            q <= 0;
        else if (t)
            q <= ~q;     
    end
endmodule
```

It is better to make assignments to a signal from a single `always` block.

Trigger the `always` block on the `posedge` of `clear` so that synthesis can infer the desired logic (asynchronous clear, synchronous toggle).

Use nonblocking assignments (`<=`) for sequential logic.

There is no need to explicitly do `q=q` because it is implied.